# Using PyQuery to ask a webpage to search result by zip-code

Tags: python, web-crawler, pyquery

I am newer to crawl data.

Now I have to use Pyquery to crawl school info in the USA by zip-code in the website,  http://www.greatschools.org/find-schools

Each time I type in a zip-code, the URL of search page is very complicated. I think it is hard to program this kind of url by Pyquery.

For example, when i type in a zip-code, 95113, then the url of the result page is 
http://www.greatschools.org/search/search.page?lat=37.3326639&lon=-121.89183639999999&state=CA&locationType=postal_code&sortBy=DISTANCE&normalizedAddress=San+Jose%2C+CA+95113&totalResults=1&city=San+Jose&zipCode=95113&locationSearchString=95113&distance=5

My question:
If i want to crawl data from result pages, how can i use Pyquery get result pages?
It seems that i can make up the url of search result by programming, but it is too long to create, and there are thousands of zip-codes to be searched.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
PyQuery(url='http://')
```

Then scrap with:

```
for a in doc('a').items():
    PyQuery(url=a.attr.href)
```